# Sqlite3: 10 миллионов записей

Tags: python, sqlite

Будет ли лагать такой зверь, думаю использовать для парсинга.

Comment: не забудьте индексировать. а так, лямов 10 - мелочь.

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос поставлен некорректно, ибо дело не в количестве записей. База данных способна поддерживать действительно большие объемы данных. Время будет расходоваться на выборку, запись, обновление индексов, поэтому, вам нужно оценить количество записей в выборке, будут ли эффективно участвовать индексы в выборках, сколько будет индексов и тому подобные вопросы.

Более точный ответ на ваш вопрос дать вряд ли смогу. Могу посоветовать попробовать `EXPLAIN` на частых запросах и посмотреть, сколько расходуется ресурсов на каждый из запросов.